# Issue with android NDK and Cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am working on an application in which I need to implement NDK.
I go through the link

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

I followed the steps mentioned their, but after installing Cygwin when I use `make -v` command as mentioned in the steps i got the error `-bash: make: command not found`.

I searched a lot but didn't get any thing.

Comment: That tutorial is really old.  You actually don't need cygwin at all anymore. Just make sure the ndk top level directory is in your windows path, and you can just invode ndk-build from a regular windows command prompt.  Better yet, you can build it in eclipse if you add native support by right clicking the project and selecting Android Tools -> add native support

Comment: @pauld could you perhaps explain a bit more, write a blog article about it? I'm new to Android NDK and Cocos2d-x, but need to set them up right. Cygwin is taking too much time; I'm getting barely 10kBps, and the total bar has moved like 25% in the last 5 hours.

Comment: I don't know anything about Cocoa2d-x.  Are you following a tutorial or something? If so you could point me to it and I could see what you need to change to not use cygwin.  Generally, cygwin is needed to invoke the ndk-build command. However, there is a windows version of ndk-build that is included with the ndk now, so you can just invoke that version from a windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin has a lengthy list of optional components - `make` is one of those.

Run Cygwin setup (download it off the [Cygwin site](http://www.cygwin.org/) if you have to), click forward to the package list. In the search box, type "make", then click the "Skip" column on the "make" line under the "Devel" category. This will place a checkmark. There might be dependencies. Then click forward through the installation.

Comment: No, you don't need cygwin in the first place,  as @pauld explained in his comment. At any rate,  NDK comes with its prebuilt `make` which is not compatible with cygwin's.